# Returning incorrect data type?

Tags: c, pointers, return, structure, genetic-algorithm

I've encountered an error when I'm returning a pointer to a substructure in a structure. The error is as follows.

```
evolve.c:28:21: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘PPM_IMAGE {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but ‘PPM_IMAGE * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ was expected
       return (indPointer->image);
```

Everything is the same yet the only difference are the extra asterisks (meaning something to do with me returning pointers incorrectly). Here are snippets of the code:

Function:

```
PPM_IMAGE *evolve_image (const PPM_IMAGE *image, int num_generations, int population_size, double rate);
```

Return statement:

```
return (indPointer->image);
```

Declaration of indPointer:

```
Individual *indPointer = generate_population(population_size, image->width, image->height, image->max_color);
```

Structure of Individual:

```
typedef struct {
  PPM_IMAGE image; // image
  double fitness;  // fitness
} Individual;
```

As you can see I'm trying to access the first element of the array being pointed at by indPointer. Of this first element I'm trying to return the image substructure within the Individiual.

Comment: Note that generate_population is written as: Individual *generate_population(ARGUMENTS);

Comment: `Individual` is a `struct` with a component `PPM_IMAGE image;`, `indPointer` a pointer to `Individual`. So, when you do `indPointer->image` you get an expression of type `PPM_IMAGE`. You need an expression of `PPM_IMAGE*`. To get the proper type, you had to do `return &indPointer->image;`. What I'm concerned about are the proper life-times of variables but this cannot be justiced by the code fragments you exposed.

Comment: The function signature says the function returns a pointer to a structure; your return statement apparently tries to return a structure, not a pointer to it.  You might be able to simply add an `&`: `return &indPointer->image;` if the storage pointed at lasts longer than the function does.  Otherwise, you have to work harder, or change the signature to return a structure instead of a pointer.

Comment: The 1st and the last statement of your question are contradicting each other: "*returning a pointer to a substructure*" vs. "*return the [...] substructure*" Decide.